# How to use custom listener without new?

Tags: java, android

I want to pass some signal to activity from my custom view. I use some code from the web, but most of them new a view to override some functions. I already have a view in my activity, so I findViewById it, but don't know why it's not work.

This is my view code

```
public class MapView extends View {

public interface MyCustomObjectListener {
    public void onObjectReady(String title);
    public void onDataLoaded();
}

private MyCustomObjectListener listener;

public void setCustomObjectListener(MyCustomObjectListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
//... some code
```

and this is my activity code

```
        View mapview = findViewById(R.id.mapview); // <---- error
        mapview.setCustomObjectListener(new MapView.MyCustomObjectListener(){
            @Override
            public void onObjectReady(String title) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onDataLoaded() {
            }
        });

        MapView mpview = new MapView(this,null);
        mpview.setCustomObjectListener(new MapView.MyCustomObjectListener(){
            @Override
            public void onObjectReady(String title) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onDataLoaded() {
            }
        });
```

the error message

```
error: cannot find symbol
        mapview.setCustomObjectListener(new MapView.MyCustomObjectListener(){
               ^
  symbol:   method setCustomObjectListener(<anonymous MyCustomObjectListener>)
  location: variable mapview of type View
```

Comment: `View mapview` -- you did not the `android.view.View` class. So, your custom method is not available on a `View` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using View object for MapView

```
View mapview = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

Change this to :

```
MapView mapview = findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```